# get previous value from a select using onchange function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the previous value from a select (in case if the ajax fails -> set the old value back)

The select is:

```
<select class="form-control" onchange="setColor(this)">
    <option value='12'>Red</option>
    <option value='23'>Blue</option> 
    <option value='34'>Black</option>                                                         
</select>
```

The function for this select:

```
function setColor(sel){
   $.ajax({
     url: set_color_url,
     type: 'POST',
     data: {id: sel.value},
     success: function (response) {
        if (!response.error) {
            // the color it`s changed :)
        } else {                
            // something went wrong
            // change to the prev value
        }
     }
   });
}
```

How can i get the previous value and change it back, if the response it`s an error?

*** UPDATE ***

the response from the server is a json with error true or false:

```
['error' => true, 'msg' => 'error message' ]
```

anyway ...

there is a select for each image (for each image i want to select a color):

The select elements are generated in laravel blade:

```
@foreach($images as $image)
      <select class="form-control" onchange="setColor(this, {{ $image->ImageID }})">

      @foreach($product->colors as $color)
          <option value={{ $color->ColorID }}>{{ $color->Name }}</option>                                                                
      @endforeach

      </select>
@endforeach
```

*** UPDATE 2 ***

i have fixed the problem. I send it back the old value from backend (in case of an error) in the json response => then set the old value in the current select

```
if(typeof response.prev !== 'undefined' ){
    sel.value = response.prev;
}
```

Comment: There's an ajax option called `error`, you don't need to use an if/else.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy this is still a valid pattern as some APIs return a 200 response code and give details of failures within the response data

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan didn't say he was wrong, just pointing it out :-)

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy the response is a json like this: `['error' => true, 'msg' => 'error message' ]`

Answer (score 2):

```
    <select id="selectId" class="form-control">
        <option value='12'>Red</option>
        <option value='23'>Blue</option> 
        <option value='34'>Black</option>                                                         
    </select>
```

Store the previous value on focus event and chain the change event on your select list to restore the value in case of error response as shown below.

```
(function () {

var previous;
$("#selectId").on('focus', function () {
    // Store the current value on focus and on change
    previous = this.value;
}).change(function () {

    // your logic to call ajax
    $.ajax({
        url: set_color_url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            id: sel.value
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.error) {
                // the color it`s changed
                $("#selectId").val(previous);
            } else {
                // Make sure the previous value is updated on successful ajax
                previous = this.value;
            }
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the previous value before passing to ajax method and if it's success then only set the value as your new color.

```
<select id="your_select" class="form-control" onchange="setColor(this)">
    <option value='12'>Red</option>
    <option value='23'>Blue</option> 
    <option value='34'>Black</option>                                                         
</select>
```

jQuery

```
var prValue = $('#your_select').val();

function setColor(sel){
   prValue 
   $.ajax({
     url: set_color_url,
     type: 'POST',
     data: {id: sel.value},
     success: function (response) {
        if (!response.error) {
            // the color it`s changed :)
            prValue = sel.value;
        } else {                
            // something went wrong
            // change to the prev value
            // now you can get your previous value from this var `prValue`;
        }
     }
   });
}
```

Comment: that`s why am using the "onchange" prop because that select it's not the only one. I have to generate an unique id for each select...i will update the question